# How to set the creationOptions when creating a Team?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

Using the *Microsoft Teams Portal*, I created a *Group* that came with *Assignments* and the *Notebook* tab. I want to create a similar *Group* programmatically.

I am using the Nuget *Microsoft.Graph.Beta 4.0.1-preview* to create Team for a School Classroom programmatically on Microsoft Teams.
However I noticed that the team created does not have the **Assignments** tab nor the **Notebook**.
Then I compared with a Team I created on the teams portal and found that the Team created manually on the Teams portal have this `creationOptions` on the class `Group`

```
 "creationOptions": ["classAssignments", "ExchangeProvisioningFlags:2509"]
```

But on the group created by API it does not contain that.
The API also does not have the field `creationOptions`

[image: API]

How to add that information when creating it using the API?
Or
How can I add those options after the Team is created?

---

I also tried this:

```
var grupo = await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(new Group()
        {
            DisplayName = "Turma Dialética 2021",
            Description = "Grupo da Turma Dialética 2021",
            MailNickname = "f958e37c-f093-4177-8de4-2f86bfaba624",
            MailEnabled = false,
            SecurityEnabled = false,
            GroupTypes = new string[] { "Unified" },
            Visibility = "HiddenMembership",//
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"creationOptions", new List<string> { "classAssignments", "ExchangeProvisioningFlags:2509" } }
            }
        }
        );
```

Which sends this JSON payload

```
{
  "description": "Grupo da Turma Dialética 2021",
  "displayName": "Turma Dialética 2021",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": false,
  "mailNickname": "f958e37c-f093-4177-8de4-2f86bfaba624",
  "securityEnabled": false,
  "visibility": "HiddenMembership",
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.group",
  "creationOptions": [
    "classAssignments",
    "ExchangeProvisioningFlags:2509"
  ]
}
```

But when I add this AdditionalData, then this Exception happens:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_BadRequest Message: A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value. Inner error:    AdditionalData:     date: 2021-04-08T21:14:22   request-id: d3a0b0d3-5940-46d8-8188-56a1eaf5d350    client-request-id: d3a0b0d3-5940-46d8-8188-56a1eaf5d350`

If I add an @ symbol in front of the word creationOptions. e.g. "@creationOptions" then no error when creating the Group, but then when I try to create the Team from this Group:

```
    var team = new Microsoft.Graph.Team()
    {
        MemberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings()
        {
            AllowCreateUpdateChannels = false
        },
        MessagingSettings = new TeamMessagingSettings()
        {
            AllowUserEditMessages = false,
            AllowUserDeleteMessages = false
        },
        FunSettings = new TeamFunSettings()
        {
            AllowGiphy = false
        }
        ,
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"},
            {"group@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('" + grupo.Id + "')"}
        }
    };
    graphClient.Teams.Request().AddAsync(team);
```

This error occurs:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: NotFound
Message: Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromGroupWithTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/amer/templates/api/groups/9ee04411-993b-45f9-8d72-63343f703105/team, Request Method: PUT, Response Status Code: NotFound, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
x-operationid: e922312859272d4ea8573cef70e37163
x-telemetryid: 00-e922312859272d4ea8573cef70e37163-0b5da564c6209441-00
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 34D331F1C0454DA7AE8CD7497D0558A7 Ref B: DM2EDGE1008 Ref C: 2021-04-09T15:16:22Z
Date: Fri, 09 Apr 2021 15:16:23 GMT
, ErrorMessage : {"errors":[{"message":"Failed to execute GetGroupAsync.","errorCode":"Unknown"}],"operationId":"e922312859272d4ea8573cef70e37163"}
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-04-09T15:16:24
    request-id: d5ef1a33-d6d9-4d30-b9c5-83a7a477a1b5
    client-request-id: d5ef1a33-d6d9-4d30-b9c5-83a7a477a1b5
ClientRequestId: d5ef1a33-d6d9-4d30-b9c5-83a7a477a1b5
'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the correct template when POSTing to the /teams endpoint.
The educationClass template should create the right primitives in Teams and also set up the correct options under the hood in the Group.

From the POST /teams doc page:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationClass')",
  "displayName": "My Class Team",
  "description": "My Class Team’s Description"
}
```

Comment: I added `"group@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups('db9545c5-c26e-4c8f-8f99-1c02321a17ff')"` tried this code and it gives this message: `Team DisplayName can not be specified as it is inherited from the group.`  Then I removed the *displayName* and *description* and this error appears: `Team with template 'educationClass' can not be provisioned using a group which does not belong to a class.`

Comment: I tried to find documentation for this, but only got this sparse information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationschool-post-classes?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp wich requires the creation of a School, but I have a Group created on the Portal that has the `Assignments` and `Notebooks` tabs, and I did not have to create a School. `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/schools returns []`

Comment: It doesn't require a school.   You only need to create a class via /education/classes.    Under the covers that makes a Group with the right EDU metadata.

Comment: using `await graphClient.Education.Classes.Request().AddAsync(educationClass);` Seems almost there, look like it requires a permission. What permission should I use for this POST? I tried scope `EduAdministration.ReadWrite.All` but it gives this error `The scope 'EduAdministration.ReadWrite.All offline_access profile openid' does not exist.`

Comment: The scope you need is EduRoster.ReadWrite.All which is an appOnly permission.  We do not have delegated permission support and have no plans to add it.

Answer (score 0):

The property doesn't appear to be defined in the [metadata](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/master/clean_beta_metadata/cleanMetadataWithDescriptionsbeta.xml) hence why it's not available in the SDK.
However, if you look at [the definition for entity](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/e49aa7d374dd749f603fbb84d2d29b3e97e436b1/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/Entity.cs#L49) which group inherits from (via directory object), you'll find the additionalData property.

Setting the information there with something like the code snippet below should allow you to pass the desired information to the service.

```
AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"@creationOptions", new List<string> { "classAssignments", "ExchangeProvisioningFlags:2509" } }
}
```

The @ sign in front of the key is because this property is [an instance annotation](https://twitter.com/darrel_miller/status/1380536724107972610).

Comment: When I add this AdditionalData, then this Exception happens: `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2021-04-08T21:14:22
 request-id: d3a0b0d3-5940-46d8-8188-56a1eaf5d350
 client-request-id: d3a0b0d3-5940-46d8-8188-56a1eaf5d350`

Comment: Could you share the payload that was sent?

Comment: OK, I added the payload to the question. If I send the Request without the AdditionalData it works, but created the Group without the School Class features.

Comment: I don't have access to the actual JSON Payload, I used the Group class that comes on the Microsoft.Graph namespace .

Comment: you can setup a [http message handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler?view=net-5.0) to intercept and log the request body. And [pass the handler to the http client used by the graph client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/customize-client?tabs=csharp)

Comment: I added the JSON payload that I got on SendAsync request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(). Formatted for better readability.

Comment: Looks like the creationOptions is being sent as originally expected, but service is not accepting it?

Comment: Yes the payload looks correct. And yes it is possible the service doesn't accept it. As an alternative to answer your original question, you might want to try to create the team with the installed apps first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http and then add the tabs programmatically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs

Comment: I guess that it is not possible to replicate the School Classroom by Creating a normal Group and adding Apps, nor Tabs. I checked the links you sent no app seems to fit. Even on the Portal we must create the Group as a Classroom so it has the Class Assignments tab and features.

Comment: It's possible the documentation is missing for those tabs, did you check the tabs for a team created from the portal, take those values and try to do the same via the tabs addition endpoint?

Comment: Your answer helped me to put the `creationOptions` as I imagined, but it does not work as I expected returning a `Request_BadRequest`. Can you escalate this and ask someone on the Microsoft Graph Team to help here How to Create this Group with those options set so I can have the Assignments and Notebook, as they are in the Portal? `"creationOptions": ["classAssignments", "ExchangeProvisioningFlags:2509"]`

Comment: If I add an @ symbol in front of the word `creationOptions`. e.g. `"@creationOptions"` then no error when creating the `Group`, but then when I try to create the `Team` from this `Group`: `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: NotFound
Message: Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromGroupWithTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/amer/templates/api/groups/9ee04411-993b-45f9-8d72-63343f703105/team, Request Method: PUT, Response Status Code: NotFound`

Comment: Also I checked and the Group was created without the `creationOptions`, but it does not appear in Teams, because the subsequent `graphClient.Teams.Request().AddAsync(team);` fails with `Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromGroupWithTemplateRequest`

Comment: Now  I tried again, no code changes, no error adding Group and Creating Team from Group. But I checked the newly created Group on Graph Explorer and it has `"creationOptions": []`  Team Group appear in MS Teams, but as a normal Group, not a Classroom Group.

Comment: CreationOptions isn’t the right way to go about this task.  

Teams has the notion of templates.  If you pass the template for the class team when creating the team then under the covers it should create the correct group options.

Comment: Last I spoke with one of PMs in this space (~1 yr ago), the creationOptions should not be used (removed from /beta already) and instead look into resourceProvisioningOptions.  Unsure how that compares with education templates / Teams though.